# Pergunta com links maliciosos a respeito de segurança?

Tags: debate

Criei [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300011/como-esse-site-manipulou-a-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-mouse) a respeito de um site malicioso que conseguia supostamente manipular a posição do mouse, provavelmente via javascript. Fiquei curioso em saber a respeito disso e fiz um vídeo para mostrar a falha maliciosa em ação, mas não coloquei nenhum link para acessá-lo, visando a segurança dos usuário programadores do SOpt.

A pergunta é, posso colocar links de supostos sites maliciosos no SOpt para resolver questões sobre segurança ou não é uma boa prática?

Comment: é só não colocar linkavel, pra ninguem clicar por acidente e abrir.

Comment: Note que eu pus o link no meu comment, mas de maneira a evitar acessos acidentais.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal, na minha opinião, é **não colocar**. Já que o foco do site é programação e não segurança, basta limitar o problema a nível de programação. Existe um site da rede [relacionado a segurança](https://security.stackexchange.com/) (em inglês).

Colocar um link arriscado, mesmo que não clicável, pode despertar curiosidades de usuários que poderão tentar acessar tal conteúdo. Veja que o SOpt é, em sua maioria, acessado por usuários leigos em questão de programação, imagine em questão de segurança.

Acho que deve-se ater apenas à questões de programação, mesmo que o propósito seja entender à fraude citada do site malicioso, mas não se deve colocar o link (mesmo não clicável) para o tal site.

Além de evitar que usuários curiosos tentem acessar tal site e se prejudicarem, você estará evitando publicidade ao mesmo, que para ele seria bem interessante numa rede como o SOpt.

Comment: `(...) deve-se ater apenas à questões de programação (...) mas não deve colocar o link (...)`. Dessa forma, essa pergunta não seria fechada como *não está clara o suficiente*? Digo isso pois sem as informações do site seria praticamente impossível emular a condição de falha de segurança e o código copiado e colado provavelmente não funcionaria. Como essa pergunta seria se limitasse o problema a "nível de programação"? Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Não creio que uma pergunta possa ser fechada por "não estar clara" porque dependia de "coisas" externas. Acho até que é recomendado que a pergunta tenha todas as informações em si própria. Por isso que perguntas do tipo "_Estou com um problema no meu menu. Link: www.site.com_"... quando o cara diz o problema e apenas coloca o link do site para que as pessoas possam ir lá ver... esse tipo de pergunta costuma não ter boa receptividade.[continua]

Comment: No caso da sua pergunta, acho que colocando um print e/ou um vídeo (como vc fez muito bem) já está de bom tamanho. Colocando o link do site malicioso, vc está de certa forma fazendo propaganda a ele, e isso é tudo que ele quer. ;)

Comment: Posso seguir essa linha de raciocínio a próxima vez que surgir algo parecido. Mas é bom ter uma opinião oposta dos comentários. Obrigado! :)